# Calculate G-Force,speed and Distance

Tags: iphone

Can any one guide me to do an app like this [link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/porsche-gforce-app-powered/id376645510?mt=8)

i.e How to calculate G-Force,Speed and Distance.

Comment: Do you know how to get data from sensors of iphone?

Comment: You mean acceleration? If not Please let me know

Comment: the _acceleration_ `a` is coming from the accelerometer of the device, so, the _velocity_ `v` comes from `v = d / t;`, the acceleration is `a = d / pow (t, 2);`, so the _distance_ `d` comes from `d = a * pow(t, 2);` or `d = v * t`, and where the _time_ `t` come from for the current _acceleration_ should be obvious, I guess. it is just elementary physics.

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: @Holex yes, it's elmentary physics and yet you know it wrong. If you had used integration for all this, it would have been clear that distance is not `a * t ^ 2` but its half. Grab a mechanics or calculus book.

Comment: @H2CO3, don't worry, it is correct, the _current_ distance is `a * t ^ 2`, it is that distance what you can go with the _constant_ acceleration during the time. a quick example to understand this: the gravity force is `9.81`, when you release anything the distance form the start point after `1` sec is `9.81` meters, the distance from the start point after 2 secs is `39.24` meters. you can use this formula for every interval until the acceleration is same. (if it is same for a hundredth secs only the distance is with that acceleration is `9.81 * 0.01 ^ 2 = 0.98 mm` but show me it is not true.

Comment: @holex nope. If you drop something, it falls only 5m in the first second.

Comment: @H2CO3, I think you lost somewhere in the formulas. :( it is easy to derive: **1.** `velocity = acceleration * time` and **2.** `distance = velocity * time`, therefore the `distance = acceleration * time * time = acceleration * time ^ 2`, at the point I'm really interested in why you would want to divide the result by 2... where would the divider come from?

Comment: "That is, if one drops an object, after 1 second it has fallen approximately 5m; after 2 seconds, 20m; and after 10 seconds, 500 meters." http://science.jrank.org/pages/3129/Gravity-Gravitation-history-gravity.html

Comment: @holex because the **average velocity** is `a * t / 2` between the starting time and the time you measure the height it has fallen, as the starting velocity was 0. The **current velocity** is `a * t`. As I said, grab a calculus book and integrate `a* t dt` with repect to t; the result will be `a / 2 * t ^ 2`.

Comment: @H2CO3, don't recommend a book. we don't need to integrate anything in this case, I'm talking about the connection between the _acceleration_, _time_ and _distance_. for calculating the speed and distance, the _time_ and the _acceleration_ are more than enough. on the paper you might use different formulas to calculate the result, but here we are working real time values in real time, not theoretically values in an observed moment. no hard feeling. :)

Comment: @holex sorry, but you're still wrong. I'm not angry of you, I'm just saying you know this incorrectly. And the point of doing theory is that it matches real life approximately. Did you read the document at the link I gave you? It's clearly stated in there how bodies fall and why. Yes, in real life, if you drop an object, it will fall 5 meters in the first second.

Comment: @H2CO3, this is the point, I've been not talking about any average value, therefore I'm not wrong, in the Newton's physics the `distance = acceleration * time ^ 2` as I've derived for you above and **it must be not divided** by any other constant. in this case we cannot use any other formulas, I can repeat myself only, we are working the current values in real time in current case, not at an observed moment after the event.

Comment: @holex yes, because there's no such thing as average and current distance from the starting point, there's only the distance. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding you but do you really think that an object has fallen 10 (as opposed to 5) meters at the end of the first second? Because that's wrong. Please really look it up somewhere. Please. I know I'm right.

Comment: @H2CO3, I promise you, I will. :)

Answer (score 1):

g-force can be calculated as a length of the vector given by accelerometer (Core Motion framework, see `CMAccelerometerData` for details).
As for distance & speed you can get them from GPS/GLONASS (Core Location framework, see `CLLocation` class)

Don't try to calculate distance and speed from acceleration - it's impossible to do this reliably.

For example to calculate speed you have to know acceleration of the car. Given `Aa` is a measurements from accelerometer, car's own acceleration would be `Ac = Aa - Ga` where `Ga` is a gravity acceleration vector in car's coordinates. To know this value one can use CoreMotion services (if gyro is present) or apply low-pass filter to extract gravity vector from accelerometer measurements.

Accelerometers used in iDevices are not very precise. Following integration will accumulate measurement errors steadily. Filters and such are second source of errors.

Now we can calculate our speed:

`V(T[n]) = Ac[n] * dt[n] + V(T[n-1])`

where `V(T[n-1])` is the previous speed of the car. To determine first value (`V(T[0])`) we have to either force user to stop her car (to ensure zero speed, bad) or force her to input this value (unbelievably bad).

Distance is calculated by the same process

`S(T[n]) = V(T[n]) * dt[n] + S(T[n-1])`

which means already extremely imprecise speed value is now integrated over time. Happy, happy, joy, joy. BTW you can enjoy the results without coding all this - just read user comments for the app mentioned by OP.

Comment: 1. It's not the accelerometer vector - the accelerometer is an electronic device, not a vector. What you meant probably is the acceleration vector. 2. G-force is not the length of that vector - it's the mass of a body multiplied by the gravitational acceleration (avg. 9.806 m/s^2). 3. Did you know that speed = aceleration * time and distance = acceleration / 2 * time squared? Highschool physhics...

Comment: @H2CO3 1) my bad, I meant accelerometer's vector (vector provided by accelerometer), not a native speaker, sorry. 2) read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force before enlightening us unwashed masses - g-force is a scalar (acceleration normalized by 9.81) 3) Nice try for a school lab. But we are talking about real life application in real life conditions. I can elaborate if you are genuinely interested.

Comment: yes please. Why do you think that CoreLocation would be more accurate for such small distances than using these formulæ? (By the way, not being a native English speaker is not an excuse, sorry. I also make mistakes myself, but that's why I generally re-read my questions and answers before and after posting them, editing them as needed.)

Comment: Because it is using global positioning services which provide a least some accuracy. Integrating filtered-out acceleration of the car over the time (twice!) doesn't even deserve word 'accuracy'. As for English - I didn't even think about excuses, just said I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi I have calculated g value using the sqrt(acceleration.x*acceleration.x+acceleration.y*acceleration.y+acceleration.z*acceleration.z).When I Place my iPhone on table it show the final acceleration as 0.99g.Is it correct or not?

Comment: @srinaidu yes, g-force of a resting object is 1.

Comment: @H2CO3, it is interesting, here you said _distance = acceleration / 2 * time squared_ but when I had said you've disagreed with me to say it is false. it seems this day is not your most consistent day. :)